# Salvaging $A-B$ and $A+B$ invertible imply $A,B$ invertible, for $A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, gershgorin-sets

Recently, a professor posed the following question on a midterm:

> If $A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $A-B$, $A+B$ are invertible, prove that $A,B$ are invertible.

The question was meant to be, 'prove or disprove', as taking $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=A^T$ provides a counterexample. But I'm left wondering if we could add some condition to make the statement true, maybe with information about the Gershgorin discs or the spectrum of the matrix? In short, my question is: is there a condition $\mathcal{C}$ such that if $A-B$ and $A+B$ are invertible and satisfy $\mathcal{C}$, then $A$ and $B$ are invertible as well?

Comment: I don't think so. I can have $A+B$, $A-B$, and even $A$ invertible, and $B$ not. Take $B$ to be the null matrix, then for any invertible $A$, you have $A+B=A-B=A$ invertible, while $B$ is not.

Comment: @Andrei That's a fair point, but maybe the null matrix is 'bad' in the same way my examples are bad (too few eigenvalues or too 'close' to zero).

Comment: You would need to impose conditions on $A$ and $B$, which at that point would be easier to say $\det A\ne0$ and $\det B\ne 0$

Comment: A sufficient condition that immediately comes to mind is that $\sigma_n(A+B)>\sigma_1(A-B)$ (or similarly, $\sigma_n(A-B)>\sigma_1(A+B)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to asking when $C\pm D$ are invertible given that $C,D$ are. Which again is equivalent to when $I\pm C^{-1}D$ are invertible.

A well-known sufficient condition for this is when the spectral radius (magnitude of largest eigenvalue) of $C^{-1}D$ is strictly less than $1$. This would be guaranteed if

- $C,D$ commute and $\rho(D)<\rho(C^{-1})^{-1}$, i.e., the largest eigenvalue of $D$ is smaller in magnitude than the smallest of $C$ (or vice versa);
- $\|D\|<\|C^{-1}\|^{-1}$ (or vice versa), e.g. when $(\sum_{ij}|d_{ij}|^2)(\sum_{ij}|\tilde{c}_{ij}|^2)<1$ where $\tilde{c}_{ij}$ are the coefficients of $C^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is kind of what I figured would be the case: it's possible but you basically end up computing the determinant anyway, so it doesn't 'save a lot of information', in some sense.